# SQL: Loading a CSV file with BULK statement causing problems with hebrew strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, hebrew

I'm trying to insert very large csv file into a table on SQL server.

On the table itself the fields are defined as nvarchar but when i'm trying to use the bulk statement to load that file - all the hebrew fields are gibberish.

When i'm using the INSERT statement everything is ok but the BULK one's getting all wrong. I even tried to put the string in the CSV file with the N'string' thing - but it just came to be (in the table: N'gibberish'.

The reason i'm not using just INSERT is because the file contains more than 250K long rows.

This is the statement that i'm using. The delimiter is '|' on purpose:

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[SomeTable]
FROM 'C:\Desktop\csvfilesaved.csv'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
ERRORFILE = 'C:\Desktop\Error.csv',
TABLOCK
)
```

And this is two row sample of the csv file:

2017-03|"מחוז ש""ת דן"|בני 18 עד 24|זכר|א. לא למד|ב. קלה|יהודים|ב. בין 31 ל-180 יום||הנדסאים, טכנאים, סוכנים ובעלי משלח יד נלווה|1|0|0|1|0|0

2017-03|"מחוז ש""ת דן"|בני 18 עד 24|זכר|א. לא למד|ג. בינונית|יהודים|ב. בין 31 ל-180 יום||עובדי מכירות ושירותים|1|0|0|1|0|0

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the table definition and a few rows of sample data?

Comment: Sean: unfortunately I can not do it right now since the server is at work and i'm at home - if it will still be needed i will post those later.  Daniel: I had to google what is it and after the inquiry I can say that I don't know but I'm doubtful that is different from the default one - Latin something

Comment: Do you know which character set is in the CSV file? like UTF-8 or UTF-16 etc.

Comment: Without some way to see what is going on any answer that resolves this would be a shot in the dark that hits a bullseye.

Comment: Sean: I can give a sample of the data itself (easy to create) but i can't get the table design out of the server - I can tell you anyhow that when i created the table i used the default tool in sql management and all the columns were nvarchar(200) or int

Comment: Unfortunately I can't recreate your issue without more details. Looks like tomorrow is the beginning of your answer. :)

Comment: Please also provide an example or even a screenshot of the gibberish text.